# Python Facebook data feed scraping - get the name of the poster on page -

Tags: python, facebook, graph

When using the facebook graph api to scrape data from a public page (/feed) via python, is it possible to query the name of the user who posted content to the page?  When I query for the fields *name* or *id* in the url, the code returns the *name* of a link included in a post or the *id* of the actual post content and not the user who posted.  I am trying to get the user names so that I can effectively isolate and filter the user who owns the public page.  When trying to quantify the sentiment of users who are posting on the page, I need to be able to hide all posts that were made by the page owner.

```
# create url
base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8"
node = "/%s/feed" % page_id 
fields = "/?fields=message,link,created_time,type,name,id"
parameters = "&limit=%s&access_token=%s" % (1, access_token)
url = base + node + fields + parameters

# retrieve data via json
data = json.loads(url)
```

Comment: Check the `from` and `admin_creator` fields (the latter is only available when you use a page token for the request.)

Comment: yes, it works!  thanks so much.  it's a simple solution, but not well documented...